# How to install Empathy on CentOS 6.0?

Tags: centos, configuration, software-installation, empathy

I'm a very new CentOS user. I came from Ubuntu. I need to install Empathy on my CentOS PC.

Can anybody explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git clone git://git.gnome.org/empathy
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=<your prefix>
$ make && make install
$ ldconfig
```

(if installing in a system library. Make sure that "/etc/ld.so.conf" contains "/lib" first.)

If you installed in a special prefix different from /usr or /usr/local you have to add it to XDG dirs:

```
$ export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS:$prefix"
```

To make use of files from source dir (*.ui, *.dtd, etc) you can define

```
EMPATHY_SRCDIR=/path/to/empathy/source
```

check [here](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/Install#Other) for details

Comment: when I try to execute "./autogen.sh --prefix=" command, I get the following: which: no gnome-autogen.sh in (/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/artaxerxe/bin)
You need to install gnome-common from the GNOME GIT

Comment: Now I get this error after I execute "./autogen.sh" : configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.
Any idea?

Comment: install gnome-common by downloading it from here {http://pkgs.repoforge.org/gnome-common/}

Comment: Installed. But glib-common-schemas missing error I get after I installed it

Comment: try installing libglib2.0-0-dbg and libglib2.0-dev

Comment: I tried to install via yum, but there are no matches.